# Show ID on DispForm

Tags: 2010

I have a view with the field 'ID' on the list and I can see it

I'm trying to see the same 'ID' field on the DispForm but I can't

Where I can cofigure to see it on the DispForm?

I use Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 4):

I added a new calculated column with formula `=[ID]`, and I can show it on the Display Form.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? Did you make a change in SharePoint Designer or in the browser?

Comment: I did the change in the browser

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't "configure" the display of the element ID. You'll need to edit the DispForm (or better create a new one based on the default). There you can add the following:

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>ID:</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="ElementID">
        <SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="ID" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where can I add this code? I dont use code on Sharepoint, only Sharepoint Designer

Comment: You simply add this to the source code of the newly created DispForm (just copy the DispForm.aspx via SharePoint Designer when you're at the specified list in the lower right corner you should see the Forms).
Opening the DispForm-Copy in Code View, you can decide in which position you want to see the ID Field. In most cases it makes sense to add the ID before the title field or at the very end of the Form.
I'd recommend to use another editor for this and copy the code into SharePoint Designer because of Syntax Highlighting, performance, save stands and backups, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to create a calculated column called say "ListID" and in the formula simply enter [ID].

That way you can hide ID on the list view and show ListID instead which will always have the ID value automatically.